# Real-time plotting with delay

Tags: python, real-time

Hi to everybody and thanks for your help.

I'm trying to show people a real-time seismogram with Python for educational purposes. I get the data through serial port connected to an arduino, but the problem is that there is a big delay (8-20 seconds) between the signal and the graph on screen [seismogram plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA8WQ.png).

I have checked the code, but I can't see anything wrong, at least as far as I understand the code. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

```
import time
import serial
import sys
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
arduino = serial.Serial('COM4', baudrate=115200, timeout=1.0)     


start = time.time()
ad = []
ed = []
ec = []
es = []
delta=0
duracion=120

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, duracion), ylim=(-1000, 1000))
ax.set_xlabel('segundos')
ax.set_ylabel('cuentas')
plt.title('Haz tu propio sismograma')
fig.canvas.set_window_title("Sismograma")
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=0.5)
line2, = ax.plot([],[],lw=0.5)
line3, = ax.plot([],[],lw=0.5)
# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    arduino.readline()
    ad = []
    ed = []
    ec = []
    es = []
    start = time.time()

    delta=0

    line.set_data([],[])
    line2.set_data([],[])
    line3.set_data([],[])
    return line, line2, line3

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    global start
    global ad,ed,ec,es
    global delta
    delta = time.time() - start
    linea = arduino.readline()
    texto=linea.decode('ascii', errors='replace')

    valora=texto.split(',')

    try:

        valor=int(valora[0])+400
        valor2=int(valora[1])
        valor3=int(valora[2])-400
        #print(valor)
        ad.append(delta)
        ed.append(valor)
        ec.append(valor2)
        es.append(valor3)
        line.set_data(ad, ed)
        line2.set_data(ad, ec)
        line3.set_data(ad, es)

    except ValueError:
        ed.append(ed[-1])
        ec.append(ec[-1])
        es.append(es[-1])
        ad.append(delta)
    except RuntimeError:
        ed.append(ed[-1])
        ec.append(ec[-1])
        es.append(es[-1])
        ad.append(delta)
    except IndexError:
        ed.append(ed[-1])
        ec.append(ec[-1])
        es.append(es[-1])
        ad.append(delta)
    #print(delta)
    if delta>duracion:
        i=0
        ad=[0]
        ed=[0]
        ec=[0]
        es=[0]
        delta=0
        start = time.time()
        fig.clf()
        run_animation
    return line, line2,line3
    #time.sleep(0)


# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,frames=30, interval=1, init_func=init, blit=True)

def run_animation():
    init
    delta=0
    start = time.time()
    animate(0)
    plt.show()

plt.show()
```

Comment: How often does new data arrive? It seems like you're updating the plot with each new data point, while it would be much more efficient to batch the updates into something like one second of data. Also, you're storing data into Python lists. A NumPy array would be much more efficient, especially with a fixed size.

Comment: Data arrives 60 times per second from serial port. The point is showing the waveform in real time, and frecuencies are in the order of several Hz.

I'm going to try to use numpy arrays. Thanks!

Comment: With 60Hz data, it's unlikely matplotlib will keep up if it needs to update the plot for every new data point. Batch the data into something like 100-500ms chunks, and use arrays.